# Could not resolve mapbox-android-sdk

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to add latest version of Map box, but its failing.
I have followed [MapBox Documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/)

secret token in **gradle.properties** file:

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=MY_SECRET_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN_IN_PAIN_TEXT_WITHOUT_QUOTES
```

Download Token is generated from MapBox site with DOWNLOAD:READ permission, as they mentioned in the documentation and it was starting with sk.

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk.sdjshdjshdj.....etc
```

My **settings.gradle** File.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
            }
        }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}
```

app level **gradle** file

```
dependencies {
  //OTHER DEPENDENCIES....
  implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0'
}
```

After Syncing Gradle Files.

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

I have checked below answers, but not working.

1. [How to solve : Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738753/how-to-solve-failed-to-resolve-com-mapbox-mapboxsdkmapbox-android-sdk9-5-0)
2. [Why is mapbox-android sdk not resolving from build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904628/why-is-mapbox-android-sdk-not-resolving-from-build-gradle)

I don't know what's wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this for two days. Version 9.2.6 works with the same documentation. Also make sure you change your settings.gradle to PREFER_SETTINGS. Add  maven {url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' } to your project level gradle under maven central. your MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN will start with "sk" instead of "pk". When downloading your private key, check the DOWNLOADS:READ

Comment: Yes, i have followed same way as document said, i have created key with DOWNLOAD:READ permission.

Comment: The older version worked for me but, that is not a solution, all people may having this problem.

Comment: I have used 9.2.1 which is available on maven.

Comment: 10.3.0 doesn't work. I have spoken to experts and they are not using the latest. If you find a solution for the latest, please be kind to let us know

Comment: @amine how does your project and module leve gradle look like?

Comment: Just for information, I have the same problems with `Mapbox SDK 10.4.0`, but everything is fine when I try to download `Mapbox 9.5.0`

Answer (score -1):

Here is how my build.gradle project level looks like:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
    }
}
}
```

build.gradle app level:

```
 implementation('com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0')
```

And I am providing the view with the token:

```
  <com.mapbox.maps.MapView xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_resourcesAccessToken="@string/map_box_access_token" />
```

Comment: Are you sure ?, is documentation is wrong ?

Comment: I won't say it is wrong but it was a work-around for me